# python 2d array to dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy, 2d

I want to create a dict from lower triangle of a symmetric matrix represented as 2d array. For examples if the numpy array is;

```
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [2, 0, 4],
       [3, 4, 0]])
```

then I want the dict to look like;

```
{('1', '0'): 2, ('2', '0'): 3, ('2', '1'): 4}
```

There is a similar post for vector;

[Fastest way to convert a Numpy array into a sparse dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877578/fastest-way-to-convert-a-numpy-array-into-a-sparse-dictionary)

I am relatively new to python so any help/suggestoins appreciated.

Comment: oops sorry for typo, corrected!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> arr =[[0, 2, 3],
          [2, 0, 4],
          [3, 4, 0]]
>>> dict(((j,i), arr[i][j]) for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(len(arr[0])) if i<j)
{(2, 0): 3, (1, 0): 2, (2, 1): 4}
```

Comment: @kap: Is you Python older than version 2.4?   Ah, wait. The answer has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with [`ndenumerate`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#ndenumerate) and [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Building a dict mapping each value to all its positions:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for pos,val in numpy.ndenumerate(a):
...     if val:
...         d[val].append(pos[1])
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [1, 0], 3: [2, 0], 4: [2, 1]})
```

And then reversing keys and values:

```
>>> {tuple(v):k for k,v in d.items()}
{(2, 0): 3, (1, 0): 2, (2, 1): 4}
```

If your python version does not support dict comprhension, this last part could be:

```
>>> dict((tuple(v),k) for k,v in d.iteritems())
{(2, 0): 3, (1, 0): 2, (2, 1): 4}
```

Comment: np.ndenumerate, great! If you don't care about the lower triangle but want the whole array as a dict, you can do this: `dict(np.ndenumerate(a))`